# Isolating styles defined inside a DIV so they do not affect the rest of the webpage

Tags: css

I'm running an email ticket system. This does list various html-emails, each one inside its DIV. Thus, the DIV does contain html code with its own css styles. My problem is that these css styles do overwrite the appearance of the overall website. Is there a solution that the css styles in these emails / inside the DIV can be isolated in order to not affect the rest of the website?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.myserver.com/assets/css/custom.css">
.......
</head>
<body>
<div>
some content
</div>
<div class="container clientmail>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">    
<head>      
<style type="text/css">     
p{margin:10px 0;padding:0;} 
… lots more of styles …
</style>
</head>    
<body>
… the message …
</body>
</html>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the `custom.css` code and also what you've tried so far

Comment: i think what you are looking for is some kind of WYSIWYG editor for your emails.

Comment: No, I don't need any WYSIWYG editor. I do not want to edit the messages received, they are just shown in the ticket system.

Comment: I have tried all: initial; and all: unset; but this does the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.clear,
.clear_both {
    clear: both
}

#ul_attachment_list,
.ul-attachments,
ul.editticket-ul {
    list-style: none!important
}

body {
    font-size: 12px!important
}

.h2,
h2 {
    font-size: 20px!important
}

.h3,
h3 {
    font-size: 12px!important
}

.nav>li>a {
    font-size: 14px!important;
    font-weight: 500!important
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 2px!important
}

.container {
    width: auto!important;
    max-width: 98%!important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px!important;
    margin-right: 20px!important
}

.header {
    padding: 5px 15px!important
}

.clientmail {
   /* max-width: 95%!important;*/
    margin-right: 40px!important;
}


.clientmail .content {

 /*all: initial; /* blocking inheritance for all properties */ 
 /*all: unset; /* allowing inheritance within #mydiv */
}

.clientmail .content  * {
 /*all: initial; /* blocking inheritance for all properties */
}

/*  To the Developer:
//  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <div class="container clientmail "> .... <div class="content"> is used to display html emails which have their own stylesheet. This stylesheets do affect the aperance of the rest of the page.
//  Is there a way to isolate this stylesheet in order that they do not afect anything outside the div? 
//  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/


.adminmail {
   /* max-width: 95%!important;*/
    margin-left: 40px!important
}

.adminmail .panel-heading {
    background: #ddd!important
}

.sec1 {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    min-height: 50px
}

.sec1 .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background: #F8F8F8!important;
    border: 0!important
}

.sec2 .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background: 0 0!important;
    border: 0!important
}

.sec2 .container {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border-radius: 4px
}

.lstsec .panel-heading,
.sec3 .panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd
}

.sec3 .container {
    padding: 0!important
}

.sec4 {
    margin: 5px 0
}

.panel-body,
.panel-heading {
    padding: 2px 15px 1px!important
}

.clientmail .panel-body,
.adminmail .panel-body {
 height:auto;
 /* max-height:150px; */
 overflow:scroll;
 resize:vertical;
}


.header>.pull-right,
.panel-heading>h2>.pull-right {
    margin-top: -3px!important
}

.well {
    margin-bottom: 10px!important
}

.attachmentslist>ul {
    margin-left: -15px
}

.lstsec .table {
    margin-top: 20px
}

.formsec {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    margin-top: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 2px!important
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 8px!important
}

.adminmail>form>.form-group {
    margin-top: 10px!important
}

.form-control {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px!important
}

input.form-control,
select.form-control {
    height: auto!important
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: inline!important;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

textarea.form-control {
    min-height: 100px!important
}

textarea.single_line {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px
}

.form_field_label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 120px;
    font-weight: 600
}

.display_none,
i.icon-mergetickets,
i.syncemail-icon {
    display: none
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 12px!important;
    margin-bottom: 10px!important
}

.btn {
    padding: 3px 10px!important
}

.btn-primary {
 min-width: 140px;
}

table.dataTable thead td,
table.dataTable thead th {
    padding: 2px 4px!important
}

table.dataTable tbody td,
table.dataTable tbody th {
    padding: 4px 2px 2px 16px!important
}

table.dataTable td:first-child{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px!important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    padding-left: 16px!important;
    background-position: center left!important
}

.dataTables_filter {
    padding-top: 6px!important;
    padding-bottom: 6px!important
}

.dataTables_length {
    padding-top: 10px!important;
    padding-bottom: 10px!important
}

#dataTable tr {
    cursor: pointer
}

.fixed_date_time_width{
 width:98px !important;
}

.list-group-item {
 padding: 6px 12px !important;
}
.modal-body .list-group-item {
 max-height:46px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.hading>h2 {
    margin-top: 10px!important;
    margin-bottom: 2px!important
}

.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
h2,
h3 {
    margin-top: 5px!important;
    margin-bottom: 5px!important
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 1px!important
}

.deleted {
    text-decoration: line-through
}

.deleteitsmall {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 6px!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    background-color: #F66!important
}

table.archived-list tbody tr:hover,
table.templates-table tbody tr:hover,
table.ticket-list tbody tr:hover,
ul.single-list-group>li:hover {
    background-color: #eee!important
}

.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9 {
    padding-right: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0!important
}

.col-50p {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative
}

h5.archived-list-h5,
h5.ticket-list-h5 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 360px;
    z-index: 9999;
    float: right;
 margin-top: -25px;
}

#mergeTicket{
 margin-right: 40px!important;
}

.col-50p:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 15px
}

.col-50p:last-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 0
}

.description_text {
    width: 100%!important
}

.price {
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 8px
}
.percent {
 display: inline !important;
    max-width: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 8px
}

table.archived-list tr td.archived-list-td1,
table.ticket-list tr td.ticketlist-td1 {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4px!important
}

.grandtotal {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.subtotal {
    font-size: 14px;
 color: #555;
    padding-right: 5px
}

button.deleteitsmallbtn {
    color: #fff
}

h2.archived-list-h2 {
    float: left
}

.clear {
    padding: 0!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    line-height: 0
}

.single-modal-content1,
.single-modal-content2 {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee!important
}

.single-p-section {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

.single-modal-dialog {
    height: 95%
}

iframe#upload_target {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#attach_file {
    height: 80%
}

@media (min-width:668px) {
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9 {
        padding-left: 15px!important;
        padding-right: 15px!important
    }
    .col-md-10:first-child,
    .col-md-11:first-child,
    .col-md-1:first-child,
    .col-md-2:first-child,
    .col-md-3:first-child,
    .col-md-4:first-child,
    .col-md-5:first-child,
    .col-md-6:first-child,
    .col-md-7:first-child,
    .col-md-8:first-child,
    .col-md-9:first-child {
        padding-left: 0!important;
        padding-right: 15px!important
    }
    .col-md-10:last-child,
    .col-md-11:last-child,
    .col-md-1:last-child,
    .col-md-2:last-child,
    .col-md-3:last-child,
    .col-md-4:last-child,
    .col-md-5:last-child,
    .col-md-6:last-child,
    .col-md-7:last-child,
    .col-md-8:last-child,
    .col-md-9:last-child {
        padding-left: 15px!important;
        padding-right: 0!important
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%!important;
        float: left!important
    }
}

@media (max-width:667px) {
 
 h5.archived-list-h5,
 h5.ticket-list-h5 {
  right: 50px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {
    body {
        font-size: 200%
    }
}

.alert-error {
    color: #a84c3d;
    background-color: rgba(255, 212, 212, .69);
    border-color: #e9cdc6
}

label.editAgent {
    font-weight: 400!important
}

.editAgent span {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px
}

.desc_css {
    width: initial;
    float: left
}

.display_unset {
    display: unset
}

.note-editable {
    height: 50px!important
}

.list-group>li:hover,
.modal-content:hover {
    background-color: #eee!important
}

#myModal2 .modal_dialog {
    width: 850px;
    height: 100%
}

#myModal2 .modal_content {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%
}

#myModal2 .upload_target_file {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#myModal2 .modal_body {
    height: 80%
}

.loading {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(38, 17, 17, 0.16);
}
.loader {
    display:none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4em;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: .8em solid rgb(102, 116, 170);
    border-left: .8em solid rgba(58, 166, 165, 1);
    animation: spin 1.1s infinite linear;
}
.loader, .loader:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4.05em;
}
.body_blocked
{
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;   
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.description_css
{
 white-space: pre-line; 
}
.attachment_file_input
{
 color:white;
 width:90px;
}
.temp_attach
{
 display:inline-flex;
}
.comments
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the HTML style tag. What you want is either to assign a class to your div and put the css for that class in a .css file, or use the HTML style attribute on the div.

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_style.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_style.asp

```html
<div style="margin:10px 0;padding:0;">
```